# how to using nested populate in node and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying populate method in mongoose.
this is my query

```
await User.findOne({_id: req.params.userId}).populate({ path: 'review' }).then(result=>{
        console.log("here" + result)
        if(result && result.length != 0){
            return  res.json({
                msg: "all reviews retrieved",
                data: result
            })
        }
        else {
            return res.json({
                msg: "no review found"
            })
        }
    })
```

and this is the result i'm getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6dk.png)

now i want to get userSender data. anyone who can help me how to populate user data using reviewSender id?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.findOne({_id: req.params.userId}).populate('review').populate('review.reviewSender');
```